# What's the analysis for たりとも?

Tags: grammar, etymology

[Quoth Edict](http://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MUE%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82), たりとも means "(not) even; (not) any", and is probably used as such:

> 一問たりとも答えられなかった。(even one question, cannot answer)

Is たりとも made up of the individual portions [たり](http://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MUE%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A) ("such things as") and [とも](http://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MUE%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82) ("even if")?

What's the etymology of たりとも?

What are some other ways to analyze its construction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, but yout problem is that you are trying to interpret `...たりとも` as a modifying clause. It is rather a subject with a relative clause: 'I could not answer even something that is a (mere) single question'.

But if you are not particularly interested in a deep analysis, you can just understand `たりとも` as a fixed expression meaning 'even'.

Comment: Is it equivalent to すら? 一問すら答えられなかった

Comment: @Lukman In this case they mean the same but it it not interchangable. You can say `簡単な問題すら答えられなかった` but not `簡単な問題たりとも答えられなかった`.

Comment: btw I was wondering where did the "mere" come from. did the たり contribute to the 
"mere" ?

Comment: @Pacerier As I put that in parentheses, there is not counterpart in the original. It is just there to make it easier for English speakers. But an indirect source is `も`.